# Error in Google App Engine tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm really lost as to why my code isn't working.  I've followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) exactly.  However, when I type the command:

```
 google_appengine/dev_appserver.py GoogleAppEngine/helloworld/
```

I get the following error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())
>     File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
>       execfile(script_path, globals_)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 695, in 
>       main()
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 688, in main
>       dev_server.start(options)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 525, in start
>       options.yaml_files)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 556, in **init**
>       server_configuration = ServerConfiguration(yaml_path)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 82, in **init**
>       self._yaml_path)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 272, in _parse_configuration
>       return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
>       appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 1715, in LoadSingleAppInfo
>       listener.Parse(app_info)
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
>       self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
>     File "/home/caseyp/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
>       raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
>   google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError

I've been reading the google engine code but can't figure out what the problem is!  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the traceback mentions yaml errors, so it's likely the problem is in your yaml file. Can you post that?

Answer (score 2):

Look in your app.yaml for non ASCII characters, especially if you copied it from the GAE tutorial web page.
In my case emacs added a weird first character, everything works fine once removed.
Also check your encoding.

Comment: Even after 2yrs your suggestion helped! Cheers!